# Modification of sentences

Tags: redundancy, run-on-sentences

I have drafted the following sentences,

> Ground-based laser scanning is an appropriate means for modeling
>   urbanobjects as it provides direct 3D information on facades and trees
>   with sufficient details due to their close range data acquisition
>   process. *In addition, economic, flexible, and rapid data capturing
>   methods with highly dense point clouds (millions of 3D points) **are
>   advantages of using terrestrial point clouds** acquired by Mobile Laser
>   Scanning (MLS) as the source data can be used for fast generation of
>   detailed façade geometry and 3D tree models over large urban areas.*

But, I feel second sentence has some alwak sounds. Specially due to the highlighted phrase. So, in these type of case, How can we enhance this may be by simplifying the ideas. Can anyone suggest some ways

Here, i have modified it in this way

> Additionally, economic, flexible, and rapid data capturing methods
>   with highly dense point clouds (millions of 3D points) are advantages
>   and **can be accomplished mainly using** terrestrial point clouds acquired
>   by Mobile Laser Scanning (MLS) as the source data can be used for fast
>   generation of detailed façade geometry and 3D tree models over large
>   urban areas.

then, would this be more readable now?

Comment: PLz dont close the question, you can tell me how can i improve the question.

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of your italicized sentence; it sounds like it needs to be split into at least two sentences. "In addition" to what? What's the difference between "highly dense point clouds" and "terrestrial point clouds" -- why are you repeating the "point clouds" term like that? I want to rewrite to get rid of the awkward "X are advantages of Y" construction, but I keep getting lost in the jargon. Bottom line is, I'm afraid your question illustrates exactly why proofreading requests are off-topic.

Comment: To improve this question so it can be answered here, you'd need to make it something *other* than a proofreading request. Tell us exactly what you think is wrong with your sentence (and no, "it lacks smoothness" doesn't qualify, because that's too broad). It could help to come up with a second example of the problem, perhaps one that contains less jargon.

Comment: I'm guessing here (because I don't know what those technical terms refer to). Perhaps your 2nd edit should be "... are at advantages and can be accomplished mainly by using ...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sentence is not quite right.  Strip out some of the adjectives, and you get "capturing methods are advantages", which isn't grammatically right.

I think you want something more like "Terrestrial point cloud scanning by MLS is an economic, flexible, and rapid method to generate detailed façade geometry and 3D tree models over large urban areas."

Answer (score 2):

I think I get this.  You're talking about using millions of points of data to capture a shape digitally.

Ok, you have three or four ideas jammed into one sentence.  You'll need to trim some of them out and break the rest up into something more digestible.  Let's see if I can help you organize your thoughts a bit better.

The primary purpose of your sentence is to persuade the reader that the use of MLS gives various advantages over other methods.  So, set it up like a standard feature/function/benefit sales presentation.  What are the features?  MLS, rapid data capturing.  What are the functions of these features?  MLS allows flexible capture of lots of data points.  Lots of data points allow high resolution.  What is the benefit?  Fast, economical, and detailed generation of façade geometry and 3D tree models over large urban areas.

Now spend some time refining this.  Organize your ideas into features, functions, and benefits, and your sentences (note I do NOT say "sentence") should flow more naturally into one another.  Suppose you do this exercise and try again.